# CakePHP 3.x: how to extend the Request class

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a plugin and I wish to extend the `Request` class (`Cake\Network\Request`), to add new methods and properties that can be used by the controllers of my plugin.

How to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your extended request class and simply pass an instance of it to the dispatcher in your apps `webroot/index.php` front controller:

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.0.0/webroot/index.php#L35**

```
// ....

use App\Network\MyCustomRequest;

$dispatcher = DispatcherFactory::create();
$dispatcher->dispatch(
    MyCustomRequest::createFromGlobals(), // there it goes
    new Response()
);
```